# Date Time field - how to get field value without adjustment?

Tags: apex, datetime

I want to get a date and time that a user has input into salesforce, as they have input it, using apex.

At the moment, if they input a time for a date after clocks go forward, it seems to be saved as British Summer Time.

So they put in 9:20 on 6th June, it appears as 9:20 in salesforce interface, but when retrieving through apex it appears as 8:20 6th June.

Basically, I just need the time that they have input to appear always and everywhere as they have input it - I want it to either save (and display) as GMT in salesforce, or to retrieve the time without conversion in apex.

What's the easiest way to get this datetime string?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried googling, and everything I found seemed rather complex. Ideally I don't want to create some complex formula based upon the user location, because all I want to do is get/display the time as it is apparently recorded in salesforce. A date and time as a string. I was wondering if there was some simple way of doing this I was missing.